# ANT war file compile failing when using Tomcat jar

Tags: tomcat, servlets, ant

I am trying to use ANT to build a war file. Part of the script compiles a source called HelloClient.java
This is a Servlet and I am using the javax.servlet.* jar from Tomcat

1/ When I use `javac HelloClient.java` at the command line I get the error `cannot find symbol public class HelloClient extends HttpServlet`

2/ When I use `javac -cp C:\Users\jon\apache-tomcat-9.0.39\lib\servlet-api.jar HelloClient.java` from the command line it compiles

`ant war` at the command line gives exactly the same error as 1 above, i.e. `error: cannot find symbol public class HelloClient extends HttpServlet`

Via IntelliJ I get similar results. When I use the `Build Module` option IntelliJ compiles the classes and dumps all the docs and web.xml to Production as expected (I have added the Tomcat Lib directory to the Library).

When I try to run my ANT script I get all the same errors as above with what I assume is javac complaining about not having the jars it needs.

I have C:\Users\jon\apache-tomcat-9.0.39\lib in my CLASSPATH

Is there something I should be doing here so that ANT driven compiles can see the jars that are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with some ANT classpath work.

```
   <target name="setup" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${lib-dir}"/>
    <copy file="C:\Users\jon\apache-tomcat-9.0.39\lib\servlet-api.jar" todir="${lib- 
   dir}"/>
   </target>   

  <path id="build.classpath">
    <!-- include all jars in the jar directory and all sub-directories -->
    <fileset dir="${lib-dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
   </path>

<target name="compile" depends="setup">
    <mkdir dir="${build-dir}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src-dir}" destdir="${build-dir}"
    classpathref="build.classpath">
    </javac>
</target>
```